# Pi Zero W and running BME680 + PiHole + USB security camera?

Tags: pi-zero-w

I just got myself a Pi Zero W and a BME680 plus all the needed components to hook things up. I feel that the Pi Zero is powerful enough for running PiHole and also creating a personal weather monitor with the BME680 to monitor temp, pressure, humidity in my home. But I also wish to create a DIY security camera with a PS3 eye camera I have. Is the Pi Zero W powerful enough to do all three?

And if it is powerful enough, then is there some good software components that can be run along with PiHole to do the other two things or do I need to write that myself?

Comment: This depends on the load and the video stream resolution you want. AFAIK you can expect something like 800x600@5FPS from a Zero W.

Comment: That should be a useful start. The PS3 eye camera can only do up to 640×480 anyway. I hope I can eke out more FPS for that lower resolution.